# How to calculate timedelta in dataframe column

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I want to add a new column in a dataframe that show a new date in column which is date in b column add months in a column.

```
a b
3 2021-08-01
2 2021-07-01
5 2021-01-01
```

```
a b c
3 2021-08-01 2021-11-01
2 2021-07-01 2021-09-01
5 2021-01-01 2021-06-01
```

I have try

```
pd.to_datetime(df['b'] + timedelta(df ['a'])
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['b'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(x['a']), axis=1)
Out[194]: 
0   2021-11-01
1   2021-09-01
2   2021-06-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['c'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['b'] + relativedelta(months=r['a']), axis=1)
```